# $\nabla_y \left( \frac{1}{|x-y|} \right)= \frac{x-y}{|x-y|^3},$ right? Fundamental solution to Laplace in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, proof-verification, harmonic-functions, potential-theory

OK, I can't figure out why I can't get this right:

$$\nabla_y \left(  \frac{1}{|x-y|} \right)= \frac{x-y}{|x-y|^3},$$

right? I've checked the calculation several times, although [this](http://math.nyu.edu/student_resources/wwiki/index.php/Advanced_Calculus%3a_1996_January%3a_Problem_4) student-written article has a minus sign there. (Maybe they're confusing $\nabla_x$.)

Now, supposing I'm right, I'm trying to show that for $u$ a harmonic function in $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ a smooth bounded region with boundary $S$, we have

$$\frac1{4\pi}\int_{y\in S}\left(  u(y) \frac{\cos \beta}{|x-y|^2}+\frac{1}{|x-y|}\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}(y) \right)dS(y), \tag{1}$$

where $\beta$ is the angle between $\nu$ and $x-y$. We use $$\int_{\Omega}u\Delta v - v\Delta udV = \int_S \left( u\frac{\partial v}{\partial \nu}- v\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu} \right). \tag{2}$$ Let $v = \frac{1}{4\pi}\frac{1}{|x-y|}$. This is the fundamental solution in $\mathbb{R}^3$, so $\Delta v=-\delta_x$.  Then the left hand side of (2) is $-u(x)$. The right hand side of (2) should be (1) except with a minus sign on the first term, right?

Either I've made a mistake somewhere, or both the question and the student-written article linked above are wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $\nabla_y \left(  \frac{1}{|x-y|} \right)= \frac{x-y}{|x-y|^3}$ is correct. It says that the gradient points from $y$ to $x$, as it should: the function increases toward $x$.

When unsure about $\pm$, try a simple  example. Let $u\equiv 1$ on the unit ball  $\Omega$, with $x=0$. Does the formula in the article work? No, because the angle between outward normal $n$ and the vector $x-x'$ is $\pi$, making   $\cos\beta=-1$. So there.